# Optimization of $group queries which using ISODate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have to get the month and year, where was spent the biggest cost.
I use the `$group` for grouping them by year/month date format.

```
db.times.aggregate(
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y/%m",
                date: "$date"
            }
        },
        total_cost: {
            $sum: "$cost_spent"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "total_cost": -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}])
```

Two questions:

Is there a faster way to parse my ISODate `$date` and use its parts as `$group` `_id`? (Tried `$month` and `$year`, they were slower.)

Is there a way to tell `$group` that `$date` is sorted (due to index for example)?

Comment: Did you try `{ $group: {_id: {$dateTrunc: {date: "$date". unit: "month"}}}}`?

Comment: It introduced in version 5.0, my question was a way before that))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown many investigations the best performance and speed, in this case, can give only a string date:

```
$substr: ['$str_date', 0, 7]
```

is faster about two times than

```
$substr: ['$iso_date', 0, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$substr` operator to separate the quarter/year-month value into a `yearSubstring` and a `yearMonthSubstring` from `ISODate("2019-01-01T18:30:00Z")`: -

```
db.times.aggregate(
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $substr: ['$date', 0, 7]
        },
        total_cost: {
            $sum: "$cost_spent"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "total_cost": -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}])
```

Comment: It works (didn't expect) but it's slower about ~0.5 secs.

Comment: Or - `{$group: {_id:{year:{$year:'$date'},month:{$month:'$date'}}, total_cost: { $sum: "$cost_spent" }}}` and `{$project:{_id:{$concat:[{$toString:"$_id.year"},'-',{$toString:"$_id.month"}]}, total_cost:"$total_cost"}}`

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned in the description, $month and $year division is slower.